# Failing to parse configuration class [package name] I need to run the application

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, model-view-controller

I am running the main class project and expecting to launch the application I am setting up an Intellij Environment and importing the project from Git. While launching the project its throwing me the above error

Comment: Can you share contents of `pom.xml`

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao please check, I have attached pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

It means you are probably missing the `javax.servlet` dependency.

Add this to your pom.xml, and change the version to match your project needs:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It is hard to know what cause this error. You may try to remove `<scope>provided</scope>` that is below  `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>`. Else, you may need to post another question and provide more info about the configurations of your project.